# Remove array index if instance object value and array value are the same

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, closures

I have an array named **var geoLocList = [GeolocationModel]()**

and an object named **var geoLocs = GeolocationModel()**

The values of `geoLocs` appended to `geoLocList`.

The problem is, I'm trying to replace index in `geoLocList` with the latest value of `geoLocs` according to the same id.

I'm still a newbie in iOS app development.
And honestly I don't quite understand the code below. I got it somewhere from some references I browsed and thought this would make it through. But I was wrong.

Here's the code

```
if let index = self.geoLocList.index(where: { $0.geoUid == geoLocs.geoUid }){
    self.geoLocList.remove(at: index)
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: @CleverError I expect geoLocList index with the same id as new created geoLocs object to be removed. The new geoLocs replaces geoLocList index if their id are the same. If the code above meets the condition then the new geoLocs will be append inside geoLocList array. But the if condition above is not working

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, if it fails it must be because `geoUid` is not set properly earlier. Please post the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using the `if` clause from the question that might possibly help you find the error in your code. I wrote this using an Xcode playground.

```
import Cocoa

struct Geo: CustomStringConvertible { //Simple struct used instead of GeolocationModel
    var id: Int //Identifier 
    var text: String

    var description: String {.  // added for better print() output
        return "\(id) - \(text)"
    }
}

var geoList = [Geo]()
var geo1 = Geo(id: 1, text: "First")
print("\(geo1) created")

if let index = geoList.index(where: { $0.id == geo1.id }){
    geoList.remove(at: index)
   print("geo removed")
}
geoList.append(geo1)
print("List contains: \(geoList)")

var geo2 = Geo(id: 1, text: "Second")
print("\(geo2) created")
if let index = geoList.index(where: { $0.id == geo2.id }){
    geoList.remove(at: index)
    print("geo removed")
}
geoList.append(geo2)
print("List contains: \(geoList)")
```

And the output when running this is

> 1 - First created
>   List contains: [1 - First]
>   1 - Second created.
>   geo removed
>   List contains: [1 - Second].